# 4clojure exercise 2

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to solve [this problem](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/2) but it always fails the tests.

here's my solution:

```
(= (- 10 (* 2 3)) 4)
```

I tried this on Chrome and Firefox, same result.

Comment: it works for me. what exactly did you type in, the whole thing or just the 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just enter the answer for the blank, not the whole thing.

In this case: `(= (- 10 (* 2 3)) __)`

You've correctly identified that the `__` should be replaced with 4, and that's what you enter in the box.

Comment: This is kinda counter-intuitive, I entered the whole thing in the first exercise and it worked, thanks anyway.

Comment: That's because the whole expression equals `true` in the first exercise! ;-)